# MongoDB 3 with WiredTiger: High CPU load

Tags: mongodb, cpu-usage

We have 3 instances in replica. Primary with 2 cores CPU and 4 GB RAM.  Secondary with 1 core CPU and 4 GB RAM. Arbiter with 1 core CPU and 2 GB RAM.

The first test:

mongodb-org-server-2.6.10-1.x86_64

```
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true
fork=true
dbpath=/mnt/mongo
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

And the second test: mongodb-org-server-3.0.4-1.x86_64

```
processManagement:
    pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid"
    fork: true
storage:
    dbPath: "/mnt/mongo/"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    wiredTiger:
        collectionConfig: 
            blockCompressor: none
        engineConfig: 
            cacheSizeGB: 2
            journalCompressor: none
        indexConfig:
            prefixCompression: false
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
    logAppend: true
replication:
    replSetName: testrepl
```

CPU usage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1tVc.png

With the same loadtest we have 2x CPU load on MongoDB 3 with WiredTiger engine.

MongoDB Stats: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mLpO.png

So the question is why MongoDB 3 with WiredTiger uses 2 times more CPU? Is it normal for WiredTiger? Data in database was not changed between test. We have the same load test scenario in both times.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: The answer discusses WiredTiger in general but not specifically for this issue. See comments.]

Yes, it is normal. WiredTiger [compresses the data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#compression), which costs CPU. It's recommended to provide sufficient CPU because with WiredTiger, CPU becomes the bottleneck. See some more [performance tips](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#id3).

In our case for example, between identical MMAPv1 (old storage engine) and WiredTiger servers, the CPU usage increased about 2x while data storage size decreased by 3x-5x. The data are also compressed in RAM so you can fit more indexes/cache into the same amount of RAM.

Comment: Compression seems to be turned off in the example above: `blockCompressor` is `none`, `journalCompressor` is `none`, and `prefixCompression` is `false`.

Comment: My bad, haven't noticed that. It may be some specifics of how WiredTiger works, perhaps not optimized for running w/o compression. I'd recommend [filing a bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Yes, it's certainly curious. Often times, compression is a performance advantage, so I'd recommend running the tests again with snappy compression turned on. I'd bet that there's a improvement.

Comment: Hi all!
Thank you for answers. We used default comprssion settings and with the same test we got nearly same results. So it looks like an architectural feature.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/okdA9WdTiuA) thread on the [MongoDB user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user), the increased load is expected behaviour for the WireTiger storage engine.